# How do I make a request to a REST controller and use data in my JSP with ajax and jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest, spring-mvc, jsp

As title says I'm not that sure on how to make the request to the controller and get the data and use it on my jsp.
Let's say I have this controller that returns me a list of User object,List

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/findUsers", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.PUT}, consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE}, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
public ResponseEntity<BaseAjaxResponse<List<UserDto>>> findUsers( @RequestBody UsersDto utenteDto ){
    //LOGIC GOES HERE
    return ResponseEntity.status(status).body(response);
}
```

now,in my JSP file,I wrote something like this.

```
    <form>
       <input type="text" placeholder="name" id="name" value="name">
       <input type="text" placeholder="surname" id="surname" value="surname">
     <button type="submit" id="search">
    </form>
```

this is my js.

```
     $("#search").click( function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    searchUser();
}

    function searchUser(){
    var Url = "/findUsers"
    var User = new Object();
    User.name = $("#name").val();
    User.surname = $("#surname").val();
    $.ajax({
    url : handleContattoUrl,
    dataType : 'json',
    contentType : 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    type : 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(User)
});
```

and here I am stuck...How do i get the data back and use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I would keep it simple.

Maybe change your controller like this. Important is that you tell your controller what parameters you want to handle it. You can use the @RequestParam or @PathVariable to tell the controller which data you want to send to it.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/findUsers") 
public @ResponseBody String findUsers (
    @RequestParam (required=false) String name, 
    @RequestParam (required=false) String surname) {

    ... // do something with the params

    return "everything worked fine";
}
```

It is common sense to tell the controller that it is responsible for a whole part of the domain as this makes your code more understandable.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/user")
```

If you do it like this then you don't need the leading slash in your function.

```
@RequestMapping(value="findUsers")
```

So the request URL will be "mydomain.com/user/findUsers"

Also important is that in your html code the input fields have the name attribute set as this is the name of the parameter the controller refers to when checking the request. Otherwise your controller wont know what parameters it shuld process. Like this

```
<input type="text" placeholder="name" id="name" value="name" name="name">
```

And last but not least your ajax-request. Normally you don't need to specify your response data type as it will be choosen automatically. The url is not written directly because this way the url will always work no mattter if you are in a testing environment or your live system. You can import the JSTL do use this tag.

```
var name = $("#name").val();
var surname = $("#surname").val();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<c:url value='/user/findUsers' />",
    data: {name: name, surname: surname},
    success: function(result) {
        ... // do something on success
    },
    error: function(error) {
        ... // catch error
    }
});
```

This works perfectly for me even with a lot more complex variations.